# Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am trying to run built in server by following the guide as explained here (http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html) but I am seeing the error as I stated in the title.

There are 2 questions asked before related with starting built-in server but they were asked before release 3.6.0.
So I am expecting the built-in server will work properly as explained in the guide. 
Am I doing something wrong?
Or do I need to download the code and compile as explained in other questions ?

There is no StanfordCoreNLPServer.jar file or something like this in the full download zip file (http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html)

I tried to create classpath definition with full path. (in windows)

Comment: Can you post the exact line you're using to start the server? Indeed, it should work out-of-the-box with CoreNLP 3.6.0. From the root of the release zip: `java -cp "*" -mx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer`.

Comment: @GaborAngeli I am trying with this line:  **java -mx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer 9090**  when I try **java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,dcoref -file input.txt** everything works fine ( I extracted stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09.zip btw)

Comment: @GaborAngeli ok, it worked with your line. So documentation is missing **-cp "*"** part. Another missgin point is that documentations says that there should be a "/tmp/corenlp.shutdown" file to find a shutdown key but I don't see any. Thank you for your help.